# axios call with different options in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass `const` data based on two conditions but I am getting an error in jQuery.

The code I have tried:

```
    <body>
   <div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-info btnSearchJob" id="search-jobs" onClick="myFunction(2)" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button></div>
   </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
            function myFunction(value = 1){
                console.log(value);         
            }   
      });
```

The initial value i need to print 1 and when i am clicking this myFunction is should print 2 that's it.

Comment: Add complete code related to this, and error if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define function always outside the `ready` function and when HTML do for the `onclick` it does not know the function `myFunction()` to define it inside the head.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction(value = 1){
    console.log(value);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-info btnSearchJob" id="search-jobs" onClick="myFunction(2)" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button></div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mmhkru75/

Answer (score 1):

First `jobsList()` and `jobList()` are not same, second you should use like this to use default value in function

```
function jobsList(value=1){
    const data = {
        q : value
}

url = "{{route('get-jobs')}}";
axios.post(url,data).then(response => {
    //...
});
```

Change `jobList` to `jobsList`

```
<div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-info btnSearchJob" id="search-jobs" onclick="jobsList(2)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button></div>
```

Comment: @SivarajuMani : keep function name same in all place `jobsList()`

Comment: @SivarajuMani : how and where you are calling `jobsList()` initially ?

Comment: const data = {
        q : value
}        => initially i need to pass value as 1  ,  when i am clicking that button i need to send value as 2 that my question

Comment: @SivarajuMani : Boss, if you din't call `jobsList()` just put above `function jobsList(value=1){` to call initial and try

Comment: can u please send me the code snippet . From my side it was not working

Comment: @SivarajuMani: First update all code in your question